# Pointer to newly created variable within attach()

Tags: r

I know "pointer" is not the right terminology, but I hope it is close enough. I have the following code:

```
> attach(iris)
> iris$x <-0
> x
Error: object 'x' not found
```

It seems that after attach(), R created one object for each variable. But after I create a new variable by direct access to the data set, there's no new object created for that variable.

How should I create a new variable for iris if I want R to create a new object for it as well?

Update: I know many R veterans suggest not to use attach(). But I need to do heavy data manipulation (hundreds of new variables), and calling transform(df,) on everyone of them sequentially would be quite cumbersome. Is it possible in R to do similar to SAS datastep, where within one data step, you can create a variable and refer to it right after:

```
 data A;
 set A;
 varA = varB > 1;
 varC = var A + varB;
 ....
 run;
```

Update 2: One way I can think of is to use `attach()`, then create hundreds of arrays then `cbind` them before `detach()`
Thank you.

Comment: The best course of action is just to not use attach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`attach()` has done nothing of the sort; it has just placed a copy of the object on the search path which allows R to look inside the object when it is looking up names.

The key word above is "copy". Which explains the behaviour you see; the copy of `iris` on the search path is not the one in the global workspace and you are modifying the latter not the former.

Simple answer is don't use `attach()`. For adding variables to objects, look at `transform()` and `within()`.

```
iris <- transform(iris, x = rep(0, nrow(iris)))
```

or

```
iris <- within(iris, x <- rep(0, nrow(iris)))
```

To use components within objects directly, you can use `with()`, e.g.

```
with(iris, length(x))
```

I suggest you read the relevant help files for examples of usage etc.

Comment: Hi Gavin, I'll post a new one then.

Comment: Hi Gavin, I posted a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13617116/r-refering-to-newly-defined-variable-within-attach . I would love to have your opinion on it. Thanks.

Comment: @AdamNYC Mnel has nailed the Answer methinks. `within()` is the way to go here.