# Refering to newly defined variable within attach()

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to perform many modifications on the columns of data frame. However, having a large number of columns and transformations required, I would like to avoid having to use the data frame name over and over.

In SAS data step, where within one data step, you can create a variable and refer to it right after defining it:

```
 data A;
 set A;
 varA = varB > 1;
 varC = var A + varB;
 ....
 run;
```

Is it possible to do this in R?

One way I can think of is to use attach(), then create hundreds of arrays then cbind() them before detach(). I know many R veterans suggest not to use attach(). But I need to do heavy data manipulation (hundreds of new variables), and calling transform(df,) on everyone of them sequentially would be quite cumbersome.

For example:

```
attach(A)
varA <- varB > 1
varC <- varA + varB
A <- cbind(varA, varB, varC)
detach()
```

But I am not sure if it is the best way to do this in R.

Comment: This makes very little sense to me without more context and a specific example.

Comment: are you familiar with apply, sapply, etc?  It's not a direct replacement for what you are suggesting, but you may be able to do a lot of your transformation that way

Comment: Hi joran: I added an example of how I would do it in R. Ricardo, I just started using R and know about apply, sapply, lapply, mapply. But I am not sure how I can do complex transformations in one shot using them. Please advise.

Comment: Thanks for editing.  Is the question that you want to modify the columns of `A` without having to use `A$...` throughout?

Comment: That's exactly right, Ricardo.

Comment: Avoid `attach`, it just causes confusion IMO.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `plyr` and `mutate`.

```
A <- data.frame(varB = 1:5)
library(plyr)
A <- mutate(A, varA = varB>1, varC = varA + varB) 
A
  varB  varA varC
1    1 FALSE    1
2    2  TRUE    3
3    3  TRUE    4
4    4  TRUE    5
5    5  TRUE    6
```

Or `within` in `base` R. Notice that `within` returns the columns you create in reverse order.

```
A <- data.frame(varB = 1:5)
A <- within(A, {varA <- varB>1; varC <- varA + varB})
A
 varB varC  varA
1    1    1 FALSE
2    2    3  TRUE
3    3    4  TRUE
4    4    5  TRUE
5    5    6  TRUE
```

---

By far and away my favourite is `data.table` and `:=`

```
DA <- data.table(varB = 1:5)


DA[,varA := varB >1 ][, varC := varA + varB]

 DA
   varB  varA varC
1:    1 FALSE    1
2:    2  TRUE    3
3:    3  TRUE    4
4:    4  TRUE    5
5:    5  TRUE    6
```

currently `:=` is most easily used only once per call to `[`. There are ways around this, but I think the string of `[` calls is not too hard to follow (and it will be MUCH MUCH faster than `mutate` or any approach that uses data.frames.)

Comment: mutate seems to be the one I am looking for. Any advice on performance? I have about 3 million records, and was planing to use data.table.

Comment: Definitely use data.table, I will post an example.

Comment: Thanks a million, mnel. DA syntax is even better than SAS, I have to say, even after 10,000 hours using SAS :)

Answer (score 2):

if you want to create a new variable `varC` in your dataframe, `A`, you can use

```
A$varC <- A$varA + (A$varA > 1)
```

Comment: Thanks Ricardo. I want to use apply() because I don't want to use A$ through out.